# Stacked Ternary Operator not functioning in Angularjs Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, expression, ternary-operator

```
ng-disabled="{{sroFieldStatus ? ( sroFieldStatus==2 ? true: false ):true}}"
```

It is inside a html template for angularJS. At times, `sroFieldStatus` will become value from collection of 0,1,2. The idea is that ng-disable only turn FALSE when `sroFieldStatus` =1, but not when its 0 or 2.

I realized that seems the ternary statement I made will always be valued to true regardless what value `sroFieldStatus` turn into.

I wonder what part did I do wrong?

Thank You

Comment: You don't need string interpolation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need interpolation. Directly use

```
ng-disabled="sroFieldStatus != 1"
```

Read [ngDisabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) docs

> If the **expression** is truthy, then special attribute "disabled" will be set on the element

Comment: You mean `ng-disabled="sroFieldStatus != 1"`

Comment: But let say if I do use it, if in any other cases, what would be the mistake in the whole statement?

Comment: @Chen, you were interpolating the value, which means it renders the inital value to HTML, and never changes.

Comment: @Shomz Ahhhh, so, actually, because the fact that the first level of ternary operation is already 'truthy', so regradless what afterward in the 2nd level of it, it will be considered, truthy always? Is that what you mean>

Comment: @Chen, Whatever the value of `sroFieldStatus ? ( sroFieldStatus==2 ? true: false ):true` it will persist, if initial value of `sroFieldStatus` is 2 then condtion will be true and it will persist

Comment: @Chen. precisely!! Look at this little example I made for you: http://plnkr.co/edit/VuwNZ7j2eion2veWCabI?p=info

Answer (score 1):

Since no answers clarified it - I'll gather what I wrote in comment into an answer.

The problem is you were interpolating the value, which means it renders the inital expression value to HTML, and never changes, there's no binding afterwards because ng-directives can evaluate scope objects, so no need to interpolate them.

> Ahhhh, so, actually, because the fact that the first level of ternary operation is already 'truthy', so regradless what afterward in the 2nd level of it, it will be considered, truthy always?

Precisely, in your case, the markup renders into something like:

```
ng-disabled="true"
```

which will never change, of course.

If you want disabled to be false only when the value is 1, you can write exactly that without further complications with ternaries:

```
ng-disabled="sroFieldStatus != 1"
```

---

See this example to better understand the difference between interpolated and non-interpolated versions:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.flag = false;
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.flag = true;
  }, 3000) // simulating a change after 3 secs
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input placeholder="regular" ng-disabled="flag" />
    <input placeholder="interpolated" ng-disabled="{{flag}}" />
  </body>
```

[Plunker version](http://plnkr.co/edit/VuwNZ7j2eion2veWCabI?p=info)

Answer (score -2):

If you use the ternary operator, be sure to place a space around the colon as well as the question mark:

```
ng-disabled="{{sroFieldStatus ? ( sroFieldStatus==2 ? true : false ) : true}}"
```

But the `==` operator will already return either true or false, so that can be shortened to:

```
ng-disabled="{{sroFieldStatus ? (sroFieldStatus == 2 ) : true}}"
```

Comment: I just tried the shortened way, but it seems not really working, I wanted to give you the solution, but I am not sure if its correct at the moment. Would you help me figure out the reason why its still not working?

Comment: The spaces make no difference (`cond?true:false` works fine, though looks ugly), and your answer doesn't answer the question in any sense.